# iOS 8 Today widget does not appear when running the project

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6, ios8-today-widget

I have an app with 2 targets and added a today widget. When I run it it doesn't appear on the today notifications Edit/ in the "Do not include" section, where it normally appears the first time with my other apps. Any idea what could be going wrong? I get the entitlements missing warning for the extension but i get this for the ones that work too ( have tried adding one, doesn't help).

Also if i try attach it as a process under the debug menu, it does not appear there at all/

I have tried deleting app from simulator and resetting etc, I have tried with another app that has multiple targets as i thought this may be the problem but the other one works.

Anyone else have a similar experience or can suggest anything?

Edit 6 Oct 2014: I still haven't found a solution, but my project does not use arm64. Could this be the issue ? i have tried removing arm64 from other projects but I think Xcode 6 doesn't allow it so I can't test it, does anyone know if this is a possibility?

Comment: I think that (lack of arm64) is the problem - can't remember where I read it though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236333/ios-today-extension-do-not-launch-lost-connection-to-device/26238356#26238356

Answer (score 32):

In my case, the reason for the widget not being shown in the list of widget was a too high deployment target number. For the widget, I had 9.0. However, I downgraded my iPhone from 9.0 to 8.4 and forgot to change it for the widget.

After changing it to 8.4, the widget immediately appeared on the iPhone.

Comment: This was basically my issue as well, but with a twist.  I had my main app set to a deployment target of 8.2 but the widget, by default, came in as 9.x (don't remember the minor version).  Since I was testing in an 8.4 simulator, the widget did not appear.  My point, is I assumed that the widget would take the same deployment target as the main app.  It did not.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're running the containing app not the extension in the simulator.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this issue when there is a mismatch in the bundleID between the app and the extension.

Example (Correct):

App bundleid: com.yourcompany.myapp

Ext bundleid: com.yourcompany.myapp.myextension

The extension needs to have the entire bundleID of the app, followed by its own name.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure**:

1. "Deployment Target" is same to containing app's (*@vomako 's answer*);
2. Bundle ID follows correct format: "com.yourcompany.myapp.myextension", while your containing app's is "com.yourcompany.myapp" (*@RohitGupta 's answer*);
3. While debugging, you need to run widget/extension scheme (*not containing app's scheme here. But if archive to submit to App Store, use containing app's scheme*);
4. "Build Settings"'s "WRAPPER_EXTENSION" is "**appex**".

*Point 4 was not mentioned in all answers (even official doc), but happened in my case.*

*I created Today Widget for my existing project in a workspace, not works at all. However, when I create pure new project with Today Widget, it works well. Then I compare the Build Setting one by one and found this difference: The one created for my existing project is "app", not "appex".*

*After changing it to "appex", works.*

---

**Also, as tips, in order to pass App Review, you must**:

- Include the arm64 (iOS) or x86_64 architecture (MacOS) in widget/extension's Architectures build settings;
- Specify “iPhone/iPad” (sometimes called universal) as the targeted device family for your app extension, no matter which targeted device family you choose for your containing app;
- A containing app that links to an embedded framework must include the arm64 (iOS) or x86_64 (OS X) architecture build setting;
- Always choose “Frameworks” as your Copy Files build phase destination (do not choose the “SharedFramework” destination instead).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Build phase "Embed App Extensions" of the app target was missing the appex file:

[image: Missing appex file]