# iOs today extension do not launch - lost connection to device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8-today-widget

I created a today extension for my app and it works fine on my mobile, however if I try to launch the widget target on any other device I get this error

[image]

I run xcode 6.0.1

Comment: I have the same issue but my architecture already contains arm64. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things I would check:

- Code signing / provisioning profiles are correct
- The supported architecture is standard arch i had an issue with this. From the docs: A containing app that links to an embedded framework must include the arm64

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

Comment: seems to have something to do with the architecture cause the widget launch successfully on iphone 5, iphone 5c and iPad mini, but not on iphone 5s and 6
My targets valid architectures are armv7, armv7s and arm64

Comment: yes i believe i read some where that they would reject it from the app store if it doesn't support 64 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my widget config from this

[image]

to this

[image]

and it works now